# Embed ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, embed, clickonce

Is it possible to embed a ClickOnce Application in an other Application?
I think there will be problems because a ClickOnce Application is not installed to the same folder every Installation. Is there a solution to embed a ClickOnce Application anyway (So an other Application can run it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for this problem.
My solution was to create an installer which copies some files to a custom location, the user chooses, on the first run after an update. So the application files will always be in the same direction and can be embedded in other Applications.

Be sure the main Application knows the direction of the ClickOnce Installer Application and checks for updates every Start.